# How can I install Python 3x and 2x into same machine?

Tags: python, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install python 3.x and 2.x on the same computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341184/can-i-install-python-3-x-and-2-x-on-the-same-computer)

I am learning Python which I started with 3.2. Now I know basics and want to use some frameworks to learn web development. Here, I came to notice Django doesn't supports Python 3x yet.

So, I need to use Python 2x on same machine. How can I install both?

PS. I am currently using Windows XP.

Comment: And a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809314/how-to-install-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-windows-7 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913204/is-it-possible-to-install-python-3-and-2-6-on-same-pc and others

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just install them normally. By default each version of Python is installed to a different path, and won't conflict. Python 3 and Python 2 don't even use the same executable name (`python` vs `python3`), so there's not a lot to worry about.

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy
I have Python 3.2 installed. After google search, I tried to do exactly what you said. I downloaded Python 2.7 .msi and tried to install it. It doesn't respond. 
Problem with my machine?

Comment: @Chhantyal: That's strange, I've installed it on my computers many times without problems. Unfortunately I am on a Mac at the moment, so I can't test it again. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

they will install into `C:\Python27`, and `C:\Python32` by default.
no conflicts.

Answer (score -1):

i didn't want to answer this but i have to since you might have a problem that no one is talking about lol

first don't install python from the official website go to activestate and download activepython for python 2,7

here's a direct link

http://downloads.activestate.com/ActivePython/releases/2.7.2.5/ActivePython-2.7.2.5-win32-x86.msi

activepython will help a lot when downloading packages trust me, so to install django, open pypm and type pypm install django

learn python 2.x and not 3.x because:

1-All the modules work on 2.x and not 3.x, python is a modular language, it's useless if you can't find modules

2- python 2.x will be there for at least 5 years so there's a long time for you to get started on 3.x maybe by then it will be more supported

3-now we are using 2.7, starting from 2.5 python started doing small changes to help programmers have a smooth transition from 2.x and 3.x, so when 2.9 arrives it will look a lot like 3.x

4-if you installed 2.7 and 3.2 on xp and lets say you made 2.7 your default version, which is the right thing to do, then there's a big possibility that 3.2 won't work, it will give you  this error: Error runtime

program C:\python32\pythonw.py

this application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way, please contact the application support team for more information

so it will just give you a headache lol