# error in running Google apps in python in windows OS

Tags: python, google-app-engine

**in google app engine**

get error in runing the appicaition

**in logs of googleappengine**

2012-04-21 13:24:04 Running command: "['C:\Python32\pythonw.exe', 'C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py', '--admin_console_server=', '--port=8080', 'C:\udacity\googleapps\hello-udacity']"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 125, in 
    run_file(**file**, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 121, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
NameError: global name 'execfile' is not defined
2012-04-21 13:24:07 (Process exited with code 1)

Comment: Please give more information.

Answer (score 5):

You appear to be running Python 3.2 (your Python executable is on this path 'C:\Python32\pythonw.exe').

Google AppEngine requires Python 2.5 or 2.7 at this stage, see [this article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine). You need to download Python 2.7, install it in a parallel directory, and make it the default executable.

You may find it helpful to read this answer on [running more than one version of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6737777/1290420)

Answer (score 0):

Also, I had the same problem. This is because I have installed both Python 2.7 and Python 3.x (the latest version of the framework Django uses the latter). I installed Python 3.x later so this is the version that is used by default in my system. To use Python 2.7 you could do the following:

> C:\Python27\python.exe dev_appserver.py path-to-your-app

Notice that here

> C:\Python27\python.exe

is the path to the **python 2.7** executable (in my case, but this could vary).

I did that and it worked.

More info and reading [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1013).