# Unknown url handler type, execfile is not defined

Tags: handler, execfile

Trying to implement the tutorial 'Hello world'.

When I select Python 3.1 nothing happens and the log says that execfile(script_path, globals_)
is not defined.

When I use python 2.7 the terminal window opens but nothing happens for a while and then it closes.  The log file says:

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\yaml_listener.py", line 177, in _HandleEvents
    raise yaml_errors.EventError(e, event_object)
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: Unknown url handler type.
<URLMap 
    auth_fail_action=redirect 
    static_dir=None 
    secure=default 
    http_headers=None 
    url=/.* 
    static_files=None 
    expiration=None 
    upload=None 
    api_endpoint=None 
    script=None 
    application_readable=None 
    position=None 
    login=optional 
    mime_type=None 
    require_matching_file=None
    >
  in "C:\Users\Bill\Programmes\helloworld\app.yaml", line 9, column 5
```

I am using the code from the introduction.  Any ideas about what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be appEngine Problem.. If so, thn i have a solution if you want to try,

uninstall python 3.3 and install this 2.7

http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/

open google app engine launcher..

go to Edit>Preferences>python path>Select the path pythonw.exe
hope it works for you

Below might also be helpful

[error in running Google apps in python in windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257243/error-in-running-google-apps-in-python-in-windows-os)

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.75 from http://www.python.org/download/ seems to work fine for me with google app engine.