# AppEngine project error

Tags: windows, google-app-engine, python-3.x

I am trying to run the default program that is made when making an appEngine project and the logs give me this error

```
2014-09-22 21:19:08 Running command: "['C:\\Python34\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=10080', '--admin_port=8002', 'C:\\Users\\eriel\\Documents\\web\\southawnings']"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 82, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 78, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
2014-09-22 21:19:08 (Process exited with code 1)
```

I am using windows 8.0 and the last update of appEngine

Comment: Use Python27. Python3x is not an option.

Comment: I installed Python27 but now AppEngine says that I dont have python installed. I did restart my PC. Python27 was installed directle into "C:/" not in program files, could this be an issue.

Comment: NO. I have Python 27 also installed on my C drive. By the way, I now use the Cloud SDK, wich contains the App Engine SDK: https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257243/error-in-running-google-apps-in-python-in-windows-os/36109549#36109549

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Python 2.7 installed try opening the Google App Engine Launcher. Then Edit -> Preferences and check the correct python path is set.
If you installed Python on C:/ it should be something like:

```
C:\Python27\pythonw.exe
```