# Getting the error "name 'execfile' is not defined"

Tags: google-app-engine, go

[image]

I have followed all the steps on https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/#creating_a_simple_http_handler on how to get started with Go, but I am stuck on an issue while trying to run the helloworld app.

I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\kirill\Desktop\go_appengine>goapp serve myapp

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kirill\Desktop\go_appengine\\dev_appserver.py", line 83, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Users\kirill\Desktop\go_appengine\\dev_appserver.py", line 79, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
error while running dev_appserver.py: exit status 1
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257243/error-in-running-google-apps-in-python-in-windows-os/36109549#36109549

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go AppEngine SDK requires Python 2.7 (Python 3.x cannot be used). It looks to me your SDK is using Python 3.X or you don't have Python at all (in your `PATH`).

First make sure Python 2.7 is added to your PATH so that will be used by `goapp`. You can get it here: [Python 2.7.11](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2711/). For the Go AppEngine SDK a small, portable Python is also enough, you can get it from here: [Single-File Stand-alone Python 2.7.9 for Windows](http://www.orbitals.com/programs/pyexe.html). Download [pyexe-2.7.9.10.zip](http://www.orbitals.com/programs/pyexe-2.7.9.10.zip) and extract it. It's just a 10 MB single file, rename it to `python.exe` and add it to your `PATH`.

Also going further, it looks to me you are starting your Hello world app from the wrong folder: you are standing in the SDK's folder, and you want to start it specifying that your app is in the `myapp` subfolder inside your SDK, which is unlikely.

Navigate to the folder where you app is (`app.yaml` must be there). In that folder execute the command

```
goapp serve
```

This will start the app being in the current folder. For this to work, the `goapp` command (`goapp.bat` on windows) must be added to your `PATH`.

If you can't or don't want to add your `go_appengine` folder to your `PATH`, still navigate to the folder containing the app you want to start, but provide the path for goapp, e.g.

```
C:\Users\kirill\Desktop\go_appengine\goapp serve
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just stumbled upon similar issue myself, In Python 3
Instead of

```
execfile("./filename")
```

Use

```
exec(open("./filename").read())
```

Comment: If anyone gets here through a vim error like I did, use ` exec(open(filename).read(), dict(__file__=filename))`