# forcing python version in windows

Tags: python, deployment, version

I know how what to write in a python script to tell a unix box which version of python to run (#!/usr/bin/env python3.2), but how do I do that in windows.  I will be deploying a program through distutils to windows boxes that have both python2.7 and 3.2 installed.  I need to force it to use 2.7

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even on unix with a shebang (`#!`) you are not *forcing* which version to run under. If the program is not executed directly (`./my.py`) and instead is run like `python2 my.py` then Python 2 will still be used.

I would suggest the safest way is to check the version at the beginning of your script and bail out with an error message if it's not suitable, for example:

```
if sys.version_info[:3] < (3,2,0):
    print('requires Python >= 3.2.0')
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the version check statement.  I'll be using that in all of my scripts.  For this program I am distributing with distutils my expectation is that the users would just click on it to run it.  How can I get it to lauch in the right version when it's run this way?

Comment: @LanceCollins. No problem. I'm afraid it's been a long while since I've done anything of note on windows. There's probably a more elegant solution and hopefully someone will come up with it, but an easy one that comes straight to mind, is just ship your program with a simple `.bat` that just calls `path_to_python2 my.py`, the obvious downside being you will need to know the `path_to_python2` in advance. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341184/can-i-install-python-3-x-and-2-x-on-the-same-computer, it's possible some of the ideas there may help you.

Comment: Even better would be to add code to find the location of the 3.2 binary (look in the registry?) and have your script exec itself with the 3.2 binary.

Comment: @BryanOakley. Yeah, that's a neat idea. +1

Comment: I like the .bat file idea.  I'll give it a try.  When I have more time, I'll see if I can't figure out how to find the binary and run it that way.  Good ideas!  Thanks!