# Using both Python 2.x and Python 3.x in IPython Notebook

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I use IPython notebooks and would like to be able to select to create a 2.x or 3.x python notebook in IPython.

I initially had Anaconda.  With Anaconda a global environment variable had to be changed to select what version of python you want and then IPython could be started.  This is not what I was looking for so I uninstalled Anaconda and now have set up my own installation using MacPorts and PiP.  It seems that I still have to use

```
port select --set python <python version>
```

to toggle between python 2.x and 3.x. which is no better than the anaconda solution.

Is there a way to select what version of python you want to use after you start an IPython notebook, preferably with my current MacPorts build?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831854/how-do-i-add-python3-kernel-to-jupyter-ipython

Comment: ...and https://stackoverflow.com/a/58068850/44330

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A solution is available that allows me to keep my MacPorts installation by configuring the Ipython kernelspec.

Requirements:

- MacPorts is installed in the usual /opt directory
- python 2.7 is installed through macports
- python 3.4 is installed through macports
- Ipython is installed for python 2.7
- Ipython is installed for python 3.4

For python 2.x:

```
$ cd /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
$ sudo ./ipython kernelspec install-self
```

For python 3.x:

```
$ cd /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin
$ sudo ./ipython kernelspec install-self
```

Now you can open an Ipython notebook and then choose a python 2.x or a python 3.x notebook.

[image: Choose your python!]

Comment: Can you please confirm that you can run `python2` and `python3` kernel notebooks side-by-side in the same `jupyter` instance? In this case, how exactly do you start `jupyter` to not have conflicting paths? I currently can only either run `python2` or `python3` code by setting up the appropriate `$PATH` `$PYTHONPATH` environment beforehand. Can I avoid this somehow?

Comment: I can run either python2 or python3 kernel notebooks.

Comment: How do you start `jupyter` (given that it is installed for `python 2.7` and for `python 3.4`) Have you defined $PYTHONPATH or sourced some virtual environment? Are you just calling `ipython notebook` ? If so, which `ipython` is that referring to - the one installed for 2.7 or 3.4?

Comment: I am just calling `python notebook`.

`which ipython` shows that it is pointing to `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/ipython`

Comment: Alright, I figured out my problem and it had to do with a pre-defined `$PYTHONPATH`, which makes switching kernels difficult. I had to `unset PYTHONPATH` before starting `ipython` and now it works.

Answer (score 353):

The idea here is to install multiple `ipython` kernels. Here are instructions for anaconda. If you are not using anaconda, I recently added [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34464003/2272172) using pure virtualenvs.

### Anaconda >= 4.1.0

Since version 4.1.0, anaconda includes a special package `nb_conda_kernels` that detects conda environments with notebook kernels and automatically registers them. This makes using a new python version as easy as creating new conda environments:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7 ipykernel
conda create -n py36 python=3.6 ipykernel
```

After a restart of jupyter notebook, the new kernels are available over the graphical interface. Please note that new packages have to be explicitly installed into the new environments. The [Managing environments](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html) section in conda's docs provides further information.

### Manually registering kernels

Users who do not want to use `nb_conda_kernels` or still use older versions of anaconda can use the following steps to manually register ipython kernels.

configure the `python2.7` environment:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7
conda activate py27
conda install notebook ipykernel
ipython kernel install --user
```

configure the `python3.6` environment:

```
conda create -n py36 python=3.6
conda activate py36
conda install notebook ipykernel
ipython kernel install --user
```

After that you should be able to choose between `python2`
and `python3` when creating a new notebook in the interface.

Additionally you can pass the `--name` and `--display-name` options to `ipython kernel install` if you want to change the names of your kernels. See `ipython kernel install --help` for more informations.

Comment: Your solution looks a lot like the solution I ended up using and in principle I would expect it to work.  Since I already uninstalled anaconda and got this working I won't be able to verify.

Comment: Works on Mac. The new kernel specifications end up in `/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/kernel2/kernel.json` and `/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/kernel3/kernel.json`.

Comment: @deltap, yes our solutions are very similar. The only difference is that your solution requires root access because it does not use a virtualenv. I personally prefer `virtualenvs`, but this is a matter of taste I guess. If it works, everything is fine :)

Comment: @MikeMüller, well good for all searching for this question - but bad for me. I really can't figure out why it does not work for me :)

Comment: If you want to set up the kernelspecs without requiring root, you can do `ipython kernelspec install-self --user` to install them for the current user.

Comment: This solution was amazing. Thank you. I got both my ipython notebooks up and running now. However, is there a way when I click the [NEW] button in IPython Notebook, it gives me two options: **1. Python 2** and **2. Python 3**? **Is that a possibility to have both of the options show in one place**? @cel

Comment: @Rafeh, can you try to rephrase your question? I am having trouble understanding what "both of the options in one place" refers to.

Comment: I have figured it out! Your answer helped out! 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ayqf55ctkv2xgk/Screenshot%202015-08-25%2005.41.41.png?dl=0

Comment: Now when I click [NEW NOTEBOOK] button, in the drop-down menu it shows both, python 2 & python 3. It only works if I am running the ipython notebook through my main installation of Anaconda (not the virtual envs).

Comment: Anybody figured out how I need to start `jupyter`, when I want to run python 2 & 3 side-by-side like @Rafeh mentioned, but I **do not** want to use *Anaconda*?

Comment: @Chris, you can do the same steps but replace the anaconda with simple virtualenvs.

Comment: @cel thanks, yes, I can see the two kernels inside `jupyter`, but I can only run one of them, depending on which env I start `jupyter` with. However, there should be a way that I can run two notebooks side-by-side, one with the `python2` kernel and the other one with `python3`. I just don't know how to accomplish that. Currently, if I start `jupyter` from a `python2` env, the `python3` notebook opens, but the kernel crashes and the same the other way around. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Probably related to my `$PATH` `$PYTHONPATH` setup?

Comment: @Chris, that will be too complicated to figure out in the comments. You can instead ask a question and include as much detail as possible.

Comment: @cel thanks, I was about to do that, but I just figured it out the problem and as it turns out - the answer below by @MikeMüller did help me (spoiler: I had to edit the `kernel.json` file created by the `ipython kernelspec install-self` according to the link he provided)

Comment: Using these instructions on Win8.1, neither anaconda nor ipython was installed in the venv.  This was resolved by removing the  venv and reinstalling by adding `anaconda to the end, i.e. `conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda`

Comment: @pylang, note that there is no need to remove environments in this case. After activating the environment of your choice, you can add additional packages using `conda install <package-name>`.

Comment: @cel, thanks.  I was unsure if anaconda would link to existing packages.  Also, an edit to my former comment: "...`anaconda` to the end, i.e. `conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda`"

Comment: My root environment is 3.5 and I created a new environment called py35 like above. I lost my pip installed packages, am I able to have this new environment point to the root bin?

Comment: @leonyin, if you want to use the root environment in jupyter, you can install another ipython kernel into the root environment. Just do `conda install notebook ipykernel` and `ipython kernel install --user --name root_py3` in your root enviroment and choose the `root_py3` kernel in the notebook.

Comment: Using Ubuntu I installed Anaconda then followed the instructions to do conda create -n py27 python=2.7 ipykernel
conda create -n py35 python=3.5 ipykernel and when I restart the notebook I still only get the python 3 option on the notebook? How can I enable python 2 as a choice for new notebooks?

Comment: @dartdog, as described in the answer there are two cases: Either you have `nb_conda_kernel`, then this suffices. Else you have to install the kernel manually as described in the second half of the answer.

Comment: The key item is that you must INSTALL nb_conda_kernels it did not come with my initial Anaconda! Thanks!

Comment: So now I have multiple Conda env's (for p2 and p3) is there an easy way to install all the base anaconda packages in both? In something like a universal requirements text file for scikit learn etal?

Comment: @dartdog, anaconda is a (meta-)package and you can install it as any other package. `conda install anaconda`.

Comment: Installing nb_conda_kernels: `conda install nb_conda_kernels`

Comment: In case anyone runs across `jupyter_environment_kernels`; apparently `nb_conda_kernels` and `jupyter_environment_kernels` have a similar goal, and maybe even some common code, [as discussed by their creators](https://github.com/Cadair/jupyter_environment_kernels/issues/2)

Comment: installing kernelspec by "ipython kernel install --user" was missing one that I need after adding conda env with a new python version.

Comment: With Anaconda 4.4 it seems you need to install ipykernel manually as discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44786736/3416205

Comment: @AntoineGautier, I am very surprised to hear this. For me this way still seems to work. Are you sure that the environment you start jupyter from has the package nb_conda_kernels? I didn't find any changes upstream that render this approach unusable.

Comment: @cel, indeed the environment I start jupyter from does not have the package nb_conda_kernels installed by default. I did not take the time to read all the comments: maybe you could edit your answer and include dartdog's remak.

Comment: The auto instructions here didn't work me me but the manual ones did! 
Thanks!

Comment: Not working for me, when I do `source activate py36`, it errors out: -bash: /home/jhelmus/workspace/misc/cdh_parcel/anaconda/scripts/parcel/tmp/Anaconda-5.1.0/etc/profile.d/conda.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: @mdivk, does `conda activate py36` work? It could be that I have to update this for the latest version of conda.

Comment: No it doesn't work, it's obviously something leftover in the error: jhelmus, who is most likely the developer of the code. and yes the right command should be `conda activate`

Comment: @mdivik, I agree with you that it seems to be some leftover of developer code, however I don't know how to fix it. I guess exporting your environments and reinstalling anaconda with the latest official installer will fix it.

Comment: Works like a charm! Just to add:
ipython kernel install --user --name KERNELNAME --display-name KERNELNAME

helps to quickly identify the right kernel version.

Comment: `ipython kernel install --user` did work for me

Answer (score 299):

If you’re running [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org) on Python 3, you can set up a Python 2 kernel like this:

```
python2 -m pip install ipykernel

python2 -m ipykernel install --user
```

http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html

Comment: Switch the '2' for '3' if you have python2 already setup and need python3.  I don't understand why this isn't the top answer, it definitely wins by Occam's razor and it worked for me.

Comment: Works perfectly. Should be the first answer indeed.

Comment: The accepted answer appears to reference [the same help](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html) as this answer. I want to understand the difference. I notice the accepted answer uses `conda` command, whereas this answer uses `python2` command; moreover the accepted answer uses `conda create` , which creates a new **conda environment**; is that right? **Both** techniques end in `python2 -m ipykernel install --user`, which is described as "The last command installs a [kernel spec](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kernels.html#kernelspecs) file..."

Comment: python2 command is included in python itself? Please give some explanation of this answer elaborately. :)

Comment: this works, but it is not linked to my system python 2 with additional packages. Is there a way to link to an existing python binary/executable?

Comment: this should be the first answer! The current first answer didn't work for me.

Comment: works , but in ubtuntu 16.04 has to install 1) sudo -E apt-get install python-dev; then in the virtual environment 2) pip2 install ipykernel then 3)python2 -m pip2 install ipykernel

Comment: Running the first line, I get this error: Failed building wheel for scandir ... Command "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptool .... Any idea?

Comment: Solved it. Since I'm on MacOS, I had to fun 'xcode-select --install' first.

Comment: Works perfectly in win10, just replace `python2` with `your\path\to\python(2).exe`.

Comment: I'm using Conda and this solution works with my current conda environment as desired. Thank You!

Answer (score 45):

These instructions explain how to install a python2 and python3 kernel in separate virtual environments for non-anaconda users. If you are using anaconda, please find my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30492913/2272172) for a solution directly tailored to anaconda.

I assume that you already have `jupyter notebook` installed.

---

First make sure that you have a `python2` and a `python3` interpreter with `pip` available.

On ubuntu you would install these by:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev python-pip python3-pip
```

Next prepare and register the kernel environments

```
python -m pip install virtualenv --user

# configure python2 kernel
python -m virtualenv -p python2 ~/py2_kernel
source ~/py2_kernel/bin/activate
python -m pip install ipykernel
ipython kernel install --name py2 --user
deactivate

# configure python3 kernel
python -m virtualenv -p python3 ~/py3_kernel
source ~/py3_kernel/bin/activate
python -m pip install ipykernel
ipython kernel install --name py3 --user
deactivate
```

To make things easier, you may want to add shell aliases for the activation command to your shell config file. Depending on the system and shell you use, this can be e.g. `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc`

```
alias kernel2='source ~/py2_kernel/bin/activate'
alias kernel3='source ~/py3_kernel/bin/activate'
```

After restarting your shell, you can now install new packages after activating the environment you want to use.

```
kernel2
python -m pip install <pkg-name>
deactivate
```

or

```
kernel3
python -m pip install <pkg-name>
deactivate
```

Comment: followed this to the dot, installed pandas, started jupyter, switched to py3 kernel: import pandas failed with 'not found' error. It's driving me bonkers

Comment: @user1255933, this is likely due to a installing with the wrong pip version. This can happen if activating the target environment failed or it does not contain a pip version. You might find my answer here interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680081/importerror-after-successful-pip-installation/32680082#32680082.

Comment: Thank you for the instruction on using non-anaconda way to install kernel

Answer (score 40):

With a current version of the Notebook/Jupyter, you can create a [Python3 kernel](http://jupyter.cs.brynmawr.edu/hub/dblank/public/Jupyter%20Help.ipynb#1.4.2-Enable-Python-3-kernel). After starting a new notebook application from the command line with Python 2 you should see an entry „Python 3“ in the dropdown menu „New“. This gives you a notebook that uses Python 3. So you can have two notebooks side-by-side with different Python versions.

#### The Details

1. Create this directory: `mkdir -p ~/.ipython/kernels/python3`
2. Create this file `~/.ipython/kernels/python3/kernel.json` with this content:

   ```
   {
       "display_name": "IPython (Python 3)", 
       "language": "python", 
       "argv": [
           "python3", 
           "-c", "from IPython.kernel.zmq.kernelapp import main; main()", 
           "-f", "{connection_file}"
       ], 
       "codemirror_mode": {
           "version": 2, 
           "name": "ipython"
       }
   }
   ```
3. Restart the notebook server.
4. Select „Python 3“  from the dropdown menu „New“
5. Work with a Python 3 Notebook
6. Select „Python 2“  from the dropdown menu „New“
7. Work with a Python 2 Notebook

Comment: This is great and I am trying to get that working, but could you specify how you start `jupyter` in this scenario (I either have to run `ipython notebook` or `ipython3 notebook`). Right now I can only run one or the other (with their respective environments, but I do see both kernels listed inside `jupyter`. Could you maybe expand your answer to include how to start `jupyter` so that I can run `python2` and `python3` side-by-side? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out - I had to adjust the `kernel.json` file inside `~/Library/Jupyter/kernels/python3/` (on OS X) and add the arguments mentioned in the linked file.

Comment: @Chris Yes, while the description behind the link is given in an IPython Notebook, it could be done in an editor. Just create or modify a file with a certain name at a given path and at the the shown content. Glad that you solved your problem.

Comment: I would recommend to edit your answer to include the details from that link. Answers shouldn't keep the most important part hidden "behind" a link.

Comment: @Chris Added the details from the link.

Comment: Very elegant solution, thank you. Worked for me on Kubuntu 15.10. The kernel shows as `IPython (Python 3)` instead of `Python 3`, though.

Comment: finally you can run  "jupyter kernelspec install ~/.ipython/kernels/python3/ --user" It  will install kernel to ~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels directory. I'm not sure, but maybe that will help avoid compatibility issues in the feature when Jupyter only will be supported! Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64

Comment: IPython.kernel is throwing a deprecation error. This worked for me: "argv": ["python3","-m", "ipykernel","-f", "{connection_file}"]

Answer (score 19):

From my Linux installation I did:

`sudo ipython2 kernelspec install-self`

And now my python 2 is back on the list.

**Reference:**

http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html

---

**UPDATE:**

The method above is now deprecated and will be dropped in the future. The new method should be:

`sudo ipython2 kernel install`

Comment: I hate randomly pasting commands into my Ubuntu install, but this did work for me.

Comment: I hear you! I just added the documentation reference where I found it.

Comment: Should be the chosen answer.

Comment: Brief and the to the point, I've applied this solution on Mac OS X, works with no problems.

Comment: I tried all the answers. But this worked for me. Give it a try if you are on ubuntu.

Comment: And where do I get `ipython2`?

Answer (score 6):

Following are the steps to add the python2 kernel to jupyter notebook::

open a terminal and create a new python 2 environment: `conda create -n py27 python=2.7`

activate the environment: Linux `source activate py27` or windows `activate py27`

install the kernel in the env: `conda install notebook ipykernel`

install the kernel for outside the env: `ipython kernel install --user`

close the env: `source deactivate`

Although a late answer hope someone finds it useful :p

Comment: This doesn't add anything beyond what was already clearly stated in [@cel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30492913/570918).

Answer (score 3):

Use `sudo pip3 install jupyter` for installing jupyter for python3 and `sudo pip install jupyter` for installing jupyter notebook for python2. Then, you can call `ipython kernel install` command to enable both types of notebook to choose from in jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at this excellent info and then **wondered**, since

1. i have python2, python3 and IPython all installed,
2. i have PyCharm installed,
3. [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) uses IPython for its Python Console,

**if** [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) would use

1. IPython-py2 when Menu>File>Settings>Project>Project Interpreter == py2  **AND**
2. IPython-py3 when Menu>File>Settings>Project>Project Interpreter == py3

**ANSWER: Yes!**

P.S. i have Python Launcher for Windows installed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows 7 I had anaconda and anaconda3 installed.
I went into `\Users\me\anaconda\Scripts` and executed

```
sudo .\ipython kernelspec install-self
```

then I went into `\Users\me\anaconda3\Scripts` and executed

```
sudo .\ipython kernel install
```

(I got  `jupyter kernelspec install-self is DEPRECATED as of 4.0. You probably want 'ipython kernel install' to install the IPython kernelspec.`)

After starting `jupyter notebook` (in anaconda3) I got a neat dropdown menu in the upper right corner under "New" letting me choose between Python 2 odr Python 3 kernels.

Answer (score 0):

- If you are running anaconda in virtual environment.
- And when you create a new notebook but i's not showing to select the virtual environment kernel.
- Then you have to set it into the ipykernel using the following command

```
$ pip install --user ipykernel
$ python -m ipykernel install --user --name=test2
```