# jupyter-notebook for Anaconda for python3 :: kernel is crashing

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I have Anaconda-2 and Anaconda-3 (meaning for Python2 and Python3, respectively) installed.

Here are the version outputs for each:

```
Current conda install:
             platform : linux-64
        conda version : 3.18.3
  conda-build version : 1.18.1
       python version : 3.4.3.final.0
     requests version : 2.8.1
     root environment : /home/jdoe/ANACONDA.d/v3.d  (writable)
  default environment : /home/jdoe/ANACONDA.d/v3.d
     envs directories : /home/jdoe/ANACONDA.d/v3.d/envs
        package cache : /home/jdoe/ANACONDA.d/v3.d/pkgs
         channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
          config file : None
    is foreign system : False

Current conda install:
             platform : linux-64
        conda version : 3.18.3
  conda-build version : 1.18.1
       python version : 2.7.10.final.0
     requests version : 2.8.1
     root environment : /home/jdoe/ANACONDA.d/v2.d  (writable)
  default environment : /home/jdoe/ANACONDA.d/v2.d
     envs directories : /home/jdoe/ANACONDA.d/v2.d/envs
        package cache : /home/jdoe/ANACONDA.d/v2.d/pkgs
         channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
          config file : None
    is foreign system : False
```

When I launch and use jupyter-notebook for Python-2, I have no problems. But, sadly, doing the same for Python-3, results in a repeatedly dying notebook (kernel crashes).

For completeness, I did update conda and anaconda (although they were pretty much the latest already):

```
jdoe$ conda3 update --prefix /home/jdoe/ANACONDA.d/v3.d conda
jdoe$ conda3 update --prefix /home/jdoe/ANACONDA.d/v3.d anaconda

jdoe$ conda2 update --prefix /home/jdoe/ANACONDA.d/v2.d conda
jdoe$ conda2 update --prefix /home/jdoe/ANACONDA.d/v2.d anaconda
```

Below is stdout output from the terminal in which I started the kernel (again Anaconda for Python-3).

Anyone know what might possibly be wrong?

Thank you. =:)

```
[I 15:24:43.388 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/jdoe
[I 15:24:43.388 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 15:24:43.388 NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://0.0.0.0:28888/
[I 15:24:43.388 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[I 15:25:02.182 NotebookApp] 302 GET / (65.209.47.35) 1.40ms
[W 15:25:27.872 NotebookApp] Notebook Google.Drives.d/xxx/CODE.DEV.d/JUPYTER.NOTEBOOKS.d/v3.d/Untitled.ipynb is not trusted
[I 15:25:27.969 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 2c3d6b64-cb0c-49be-bcdf-cc8aefe80afd
[I 15:25:30.969 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
[W 15:25:38.209 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 2c3d6b64-cb0c-49be-bcdf-cc8aefe80afd
[I 15:25:39.973 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
WARNING:root:kernel 2c3d6b64-cb0c-49be-bcdf-cc8aefe80afd restarted
[I 15:25:42.976 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5)
WARNING:root:kernel 2c3d6b64-cb0c-49be-bcdf-cc8aefe80afd restarted
[I 15:25:45.979 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5)
WARNING:root:kernel 2c3d6b64-cb0c-49be-bcdf-cc8aefe80afd restarted
[I 15:25:48.984 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5)
WARNING:root:kernel 2c3d6b64-cb0c-49be-bcdf-cc8aefe80afd restarted
[W 15:25:51.989 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 15:25:51.989 NotebookApp] Kernel 2c3d6b64-cb0c-49be-bcdf-cc8aefe80afd died, removing from map.
ERROR:root:kernel 2c3d6b64-cb0c-49be-bcdf-cc8aefe80afd restarted failed!
[W 15:25:52.033 NotebookApp] Kernel deleted before session
```

Comment: a side note: having several versions of anaconda is rather messy. Creating environments instead is much easier and less error prone. This may interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook/30492913#30492913

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Btw, the pointed to suggestion (URL) needs some additional steps included (mostly adding pip packages -- ... perhaps it didn't before); but I didn't know that the Python-2 version of Anaconda could create an virtualenv for Python-3 and vice versa, which is very useful. So I up-voted your side note. :). (Thank you). My original problem persists, but that's a separate issue (possibly a bug).