# Is it possible to run a pypy kernel in the Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pypy, jupyter

I have always wondered if it were possible to run PyPy in the Jupyter notebook. I recently tried installing PyPy on my local machine, and it ran really well - 100X speedup in an agent-based simulation written in pure Python. However, I miss the interactivity in the Jupyter notebook. Is it possible to make the IPython kernel use PyPy rather than CPython?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Provided you have a system-wide / user installation of `jupyter`. You can follow:

```
pypy3 -m venv PyPy3
source PyPy3/bin/activate  # in POSIX, or...
PyPy3\Scripts\activate.bat  # in Windows
pypy3 -m pip install ipykernel
ipython kernel install --user --name=PyPy3
```

Now exit the virtual environment and verify installation:

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

Open Jupyter notebook or lab interface.

Comment: Confirmed to work with macOS 10.14.4 and pypy3 7.1.1-beta0 from Homebrew. Jupyter was installed from Anaconda installer and launched with Anaconda-Navigator. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @jadelord. It should be the accepted answer! Simple and very convenient.

Comment: Thanks @paugier (small world ;) ). [You might also find these aliases useful](https://gist.github.com/ashwinvis/9de22a0190a16717691783d22c2d0a46#file-python_aliases-sh-L11-L16)

Comment: 2021 UPDATE HERE (WINDOWS):


I've used this code except I had an issue with the second line:

source PyPy3/bin/activate

I had to replace it with:

PyPy3\Scripts\activate.bat

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Answer (score 12):

You can install Jupyter with pypy:

```
pypy-pip install jupyter
```

The are problems on Mac OS X. If the install fails complaining a about `gnureadline`. Try this:

```
pypy-pip install --no-deps jupyter
```

Than start with:

```
pypy-ipython notebook
```

My `pypy-ipython` looks like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/pypy

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from IPython import start_ipython

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
```

In a notebook:

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.version

Out[2]:

'2.7.9 (295ee98b6928, May 31 2015, 07:28:49)\n[PyPy 2.6.0 with GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)]'
```

The notebook requires Python 2.7 or 3.3+. PyPy for Python3.3 should be out soon.

My `pypy-pip` this executable file `/usr/local/bin//pypy-pip` with this content:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/pypy
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'pip','console_scripts','pip'
__requires__ = 'pip'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('pip', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Mike! How do I get the tool `pypy-pip`? I currently already have pip and setuptools installed for pypy and pypy3, set up in roughly the same way as the anaconda Python (in a separate directory under my home folder).

Comment: My apologies for posting this second one fast... but I realized I can do `pypy -m pip install package_name` or `pypy3 -m pip install package_name` only after posting my comment.

Comment: Added the content of `pypy-pip`.

Comment: Doesn't this make the whole thing run under PyPy instead of just the kernel?

Comment: Yes, here the whole things is the kernel. The OP wants to use PyPy in the Notebook. You can also [run different kernels with one Notebook server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook/30493155#30493155).

Comment: @MikeMüller The link you shared doesn't mention pypy. Can you add an answer here that gives details on how to just add a pypy kernel capability to an existing non-pypy jupyter installation?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe we can follow the [official doc](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html):

```
pypy3 -m pip install ipykernel
pypy3 -m ipykernel install --user
```

Answer (score 1):

The first answer worked great for me on Ubuntu, but did not work on Fedora - zeromq failed to compile

The following worked for me, based on the first answer:

- Download portable pypy from https://github.com/squeaky-pl/portable-pypy
- Extract to a local directory (should be kept there as long as used)
- Run the following:

```
$ cd <portable-pypy-directory>
$ bin/python3 virtualenv/virtualenv.py <new-venv-dir>
$ <new-venv-dir>/bin/activate
$ pip install jupyter
$ ipython kernel install --user --name=PyPy3
```

Comment: For a year or two portable pypy is not needed unless you want older versions. The downloads at https://downloads.python.org/pypy/ are already "portable", and for an even better experience use conda since they compile packages for linux (x86 and arm64) and macOS, and hopefully soon for windows

Comment: https://conda-forge.org/blog/posts/2020-03-10-pypy/

Answer (score 0):

(Tested in Ubuntu Linux)
To install pypy, make a virtual environment and run jupyter notebook as with python:
Download pypy version (3.8 example here)
in a terminal run following commands
to decompress

```
tar xf pypy3.8-v7.3.9-linux64.tar.bz2
```

upgrade pip and wheel

```
./pypy3.8-v7.3.9-linux64/bin/pypy -m ensurepip --default-pip
./pypy3.8-v7.3.9-linux64/bin/pypy -mpip install -U pip wheel
```

create virtual env the following way is crucial

```
./pypy3.8-v7.3.9-linux64/bin/pypy -m venv my-pypy-env
```

activate environment

```
source my-pypy-env/bin/activate
```

pip install jupyter and any other library

```
pip install jupyter
```

open jupyter as always

```
jupyter notebook
```