# Issue whilst installing the pypy kernel to jupyter notebook

Tags: python, cmd, jupyter-notebook, failed-installation, pypy

I am trying to install pypy3 to jupyter notebook but whilst doing it, it gives me an error at the source code bit during the cmd installation. I am on windows 10 64 bit system. Would this bit affect anything, from my backtests of large files the runtime has not been that much better in comparison to python which makes me believe that pypy is not working properly. I am trying to execute the answer to this previous question on stack overflow: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850577/is-it-possible-to-run-a-pypy-kernel-in-the-jupyter-notebook). even though that `source PyPy3/bin/activate` bit of the code does not work, the pypy kernel shows up on jupyter notebook.

cmd codes for jupyter notebook installation:

```
pypy3 -m venv PyPy3
source PyPy3/bin/activate
pypy3 -m pip install ipykernel
ipython kernel install --user --name=PyPy3
```

cmd results- note that all the other commands worked except for `source PyPy3/bin/activate`:

```
C:\Users\maste>pypy3 -m venv PyPy3

C:\Users\maste>source PyPy3/bin/activate
'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Jupyter Notebook:

[image]

Comment: @jadelord sorry for tagging you in this but you had the answered the links question above 5 years ago. Reckoned you could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use `source` in a command prompt on Windows. That won't work, `source` is for POSIX environments.

Instead, try:

```
PyPy3\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Check out the [`venv` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) for more information. It contains this handy table of commands for activating a virtual environment:

[image: Activating a virtual environment]