# Selecting kernel when opening ipython Notebook with Anaconda in Windows

Tags: python, kernel, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have both installed (Python 2.7 and 3.5), and I have Anaconda2\python as my Project Interpreter on PyCharm. However, this doesn't seem to be enough to get ipython Notebook to open up using Python 2.7.

How can I make iPython Notebook to default to Python 2, as opposed to 3, or give me an option to select which one I open Notebook with?

Right now, it is not even an option to select the kernel (?) from within Notebook:

[image]

Even after following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30492913/4089351), there is only one kernel option:

[image]

Interestingly, I see what I want (separate options for Python 2 and 3) **only** when I have a proprietary software environment activated, and then I open Notebook:

[image]

This is not a workable solution, since this product is a trial version. Plus there ought to be a way of making both kernels available independent of this workaround.

Comment: Have a look at the instructions here: http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-python-2-and-3

Comment: I had looked at it, but it sound and either/or selection, wheras I want to have both kernels available.

Comment: It's not either/or - if you're running jupyter with Python 3, those steps will set up a Python 2 kernel in addition to the Python 3 kernel that's already available.

Comment: Thank you. Do you want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-python-2-and-3) are the instructions to make a Python 2 kernel available in addition to the Python 3 kernel that's already there. Copied in:

If you’re running Jupyter on Python 3, you can set up a Python 2 kernel like this:

```
python2 -m pip install ipykernel
python2 -m ipykernel install --user
```

Or using conda, create a Python 2 environment:

```
conda create -n ipykernel_py2 python=2 ipykernel
source activate ipykernel_py2    # On Windows, remove the word 'source'
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

If you’re running Jupyter on Python 2 and want to set up a Python 3 kernel, follow the same steps, replacing 2 with 3.

The last command installs a kernel spec file for the current python installation. Kernel spec files are JSON files, which can be viewed and changed with a normal text editor.