# Packages from Conda env not found in Jupyer Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, ipython

I created an environment called imagescraper and installed pip with it.

I then proceed to use pip to install a package called ImageScraper;

```
>>activate imagescraper
[imagescraper]>>pip install ImageScraper
```

Just to ensure that I have the package successfully installed:

```
>>conda list

[imagescraper] C:\Users\John>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Anaconda2\envs\imagescrap
#
future                    0.15.2                    <pip>
imagescraper              2.0.7                     <pip>
lxml                      3.6.0                     <pip>
numpy                     1.11.0                    <pip>
pandas                    0.18.0                    <pip>
pip                       8.1.1                    py27_1
python                    2.7.11                        4
python-dateutil           2.5.2                     <pip>
pytz                      2016.3                    <pip>
requests                  2.9.1                     <pip>
setproctitle              1.1.9                     <pip>
setuptools                20.3                     py27_0
simplepool                0.1                       <pip>
six                       1.10.0                    <pip>
vs2008_runtime            9.00.30729.1                  0
wheel                     0.29.0                   py27_0
```

Before I launch Jupyter notebook, just to check where we are getting the path from:

```
[imagescraper] C:\Users\John>python
Python 2.7.11 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:58:36) [MSC
v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Anaconda2\\envs\\imagescraper\\python.exe'
>>> import image_scraper
```

Seems ok, so I proceed to launch Jupyter notebook using

```
[imagescraper]>>jupyter notebook
```

Within the notebook I created a new book and when i tried the same;

```
import image_scraper
```

I am returned with:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6c2b65c9cdeb> in <module>()
----> 1 import image_scraper

ImportError: No module named image_scraper
```

Doing the same to check the paths within Jupyter notebook, I get this;

```
import sys

sys.executable

'C:\\Anaconda2\\python.exe'
```

Which tells me that it is not referring to the environment where I installed the modules in.

Is there a way I can ensure that my notebooks all refer to its own env packages?

Comment: yes, you either:  install a ipykernel in your `imagescraper` environment. You can use my answer here as a template: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook/. Or: install jupyter in your `imagescraper` environment and start jupyter from this environment.

Comment: thanks that totally worked out for me!

Comment: @cel you should expand that into an answer :-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions:

You can register a new kernel based on your `imagescraper` environment. The kernel will start from the `imagescraper` environment and thus sees all its packages.

```
source activate imagescraper
conda install ipykernel
ipython kernel install --name imagescraper
```

This will add a new kernel named `imagescraper` to your jupyter dashboard.

---

Another solution is to install jupyter notebook into the `imagescraper` environment and start jupyter from the enviroment. This requires activating `imagescraper` whenever you start jupyter notebook.

```
source activate imagescraper
conda install notebook
jupyter notebook
```

Comment: Thanks! I somehow prefer to just install jupyter in all my separate envs. Works like a charm.