# Add venv to python jupyter notebook but pip list output not match

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-venv

After create venv from terminal, i tried add the new env into jupyter notebook:

[image]

and restart kernel with `env_test`, run the pip list:

[image]

Why these two env pip list are not matching?

Comment: Are you using a pyenv or conda? If this is the case, please try restarting your jupyter notebook server then try again.

Comment: I suppose your issue is same as [jupyter not using version set by pyenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43914573/jupyter-not-using-version-set-by-pyenv)

Comment: I am using in pyenv (create venv with `python -m venv env_name`)
and tried restart the notebook server still the same.

Comment: I'm sorry that I have no windows environment to try, I wish these articles could help: 
[Using IPython / Jupyter Notebooks Under Version Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734739/using-ipython-jupyter-notebooks-under-version-control), [How to change the Jupyter start-up folder - might inspire how to change config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254852/how-to-change-the-jupyter-start-up-folder).