# Conda list shows python package but error 'module not found' occurs

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, environment, pyomo

I am forced to work on windows and I need to install pyomo. Seems like anaconda is the way to do that. I installed the package via `conda install` and `conda list` also shows me that it's installed. But when I run jupyter notebook via the anaconda screen the pyomo package is not in the environment and the error 'module not found' occurs.

What am I missing here when I install packages?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to select your environment on the homepage of jupyter? Also refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382508/packages-from-conda-env-not-found-in-jupyer-notebook

Comment: I thought that should be possible. It wasn't. But I finally saw that in anaconda you can choose the environment. That did the trick.

Comment: Great! The later releases of Jupyter seem to allow you to select your environment in the UI. Hope it helped.

Comment: That’s a good feature. It doesn’t seem to be integrated in anaconda yet. Thanks Bernard

Answer (score 1):

This error drove me crazy, I finally figured it out.

```
conda install -n yourEnv yourPackage
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed everything with miniconda and then chose in the menu up left of the anaconda sceen the miniconda3 environment. Did the trick.