# How to run jupyterlab version in a specific Conda envs on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter-lab

I've been working with my jupyterlab from my GCP, but recently I wanted to downgrade a certain version of a package and needed to create a conda env.

Unfortunately, after setting up my conda env I'm unable to open the jupyterlab version in my conda envs, when I run jupyterlab I still only get the main Jupiterlab (with the wrong version of the package)

Comment: This is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382508/packages-from-conda-env-not-found-in-jupyer-notebook. If you choose to go the kernel way, see also my answer here for an easier solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30492913/2272172

Comment: Please edit your post and add exactly what you did and also this error.

Comment: Hi, cel

I followed the instruction in the section 'Manually registering kernels' from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook/30492913#30492913), I finally end-up updating completely my anaconda and now the kernels are working but strangely I'm now on python 3.5.

I'm now trying to bring back my python version to the latest one. 

Thank you for your help.