# RDKit in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda, ubuntu-18.04, rdkit

I want to use RDKit in a Jupyter Notebook.

I created a conda environment with rdkit, jupyter, and other packages installed.

I can open the Jupyter Notebook and import and use packages like pandas, but I can't import rdkit. It says "no module named rdkit", even though it is installed in the environment just like the other packages. What am I doing wrong? Is rdkit not compatible with Jupyter Notebooks?

I'm using Ubuntu18.04, and the Python version in my conda environment is 3.6.

Comment: You need to make sure that the jupyter kernel you are currently using matches the python interpreter you installed rdkit to. See here for a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382508/packages-from-conda-env-not-found-in-jupyer-notebook/36395096#36395096

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved it!