# Installing geopandas

Tags: python, installation, jupyter, conda, geopandas

I've tried installing geopandas, but I keep running into issues. I've followed the instructions here:
https://geopandas.org/install.htm

Trying `conda install geopandas` in my terminal produced a number of conflicts. Similarly with `conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas`. I just tried

```
conda create -n geo_env
conda activate geo_env
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
conda install python=3 geopandas
```

as instructed on the site, and it seemed to install properly, that is I saw the same sort of prompts and output as outlined in the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLezhLLp3oQ).

But when I try `import geopandas as gpd` in my jupyter notebook, I get the error "No module named 'geopandas'".

I'm not super comfortable with the terminal and doing under-the-hood type coding, and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this. It seems that the latter instructions for the install created a new environment? How can I get Anaconda (or my jupyter notebook) to locate this environment?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: remove jupyter from the equation. if you launch a bare python interpreter, can you import geopandas

Comment: this might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382508/packages-from-conda-env-not-found-in-jupyer-notebook

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure the issues with the conda install. I was able to install it properly in a new environment in Anaconda-Navigator, but still unable to access it through a jupyter notebook.

However I tried `pip install geopandas` instead of conda install, and that seems to have worked perfectly. Funny, since `pip install` seemed to be discouraged on the [geopandas doc site](https://geopandas.org/install.html). Either way, I seem to have geopandas installed properly now!