# Installing Python3 and Python2 in Jupyter Notebooks with modules: Windows 10

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

There is lots of information on trying to resolve problems with multiple Pythons on Jupyter notebooks. I would simply like to know how to do a clean install of Anaconda Python3 and Anaconda Python2, have them both work with Jupyter Notebooks and how to make modules such as Numpy, Matplotlib, pandas etc. work with both environments in Windows 10

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook/30492913#30492913