# How to make jupyter notebook find other virtual environment in CentOS?

Tags: python, centos, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I installed Anaconda3 in CentOS and created several virtual environments. Then, I installed the juypter notebook in every virtual environment.

After that, I started Jupyter notebook, unfortunately, the Jupyter notebook can only detect own environment.

I also found this post:

[Link Conda environment with Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37433363/link-conda-environment-with-jupyter-notebook)

But I can not find this "kernel.json" file in CentOS.

What shall I do?

Comment: 1) Did you use `virtualenv`s or conda environments? 2) Try installing the `ipykernel` package in each conda environment, and uninstalling `notebook` in each environment except one

Comment: @darthbith I used the conda environments. I followed your instruction install ed the ipykernel, but it reported that, the ipykernel has already been installed. Then, I deleted the jupyter in every virtual environment, but the it still can not find any environment.