# install spacy not working in jupyter notebook

Tags: anaconda, spacy

I have installed Anaconda 3.x for 64 bit in a Windows 10 system. I have installed spacy by `pip install -U spacy`

WHen i run `install spacy` in Notebook i get an 'DLL Load' error like this

[image]

Comment: Which Python version are you using? [Here's an issue](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1027#issuecomment-300051392) describing the same problem and a potential solution – have you tried creating a conda environment and explicitly setting `python=3`, i.e. `conda create --name py36 python=3`?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. I am still new to Python so maybe i am making some silly mistakes. I am able pip install spacy AFTER i installed VS express, as that link suggests, but i continue to get that import error.Thanks

Comment: Tried `conda install -c spacy spacy=0.101.0`?

Comment: Yes i did. I managed to get PyCharm to work with Spacy, by setting the Interpreter to point to the conda environment. I need to find a way for Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: @InesMontani I managed to set the conda environment, install spacy in it and get it work in Python command line as well as PyCharm. Notebook is my issue now.

Comment: Thanks all. I managed to connect to the conda environment in Notebook as per this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37433363/link-conda-environment-with-jupyter-notebook

Answer (score 8):

You can install spacy and download en in the jupyter notebook as:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install spacy
!{sys.executable} -m spacy download en
```

Answer (score 2):

> !conda install -c spacy spacy=0.101.0 -y
>
> !python -m spacy.en.download

Answer (score 1):

```
! pip install SpaCy
! python -m spacy download en
```

This really worked !

Answer (score 0):

To install spacy on jupyter notebook use `pip install SpaCy`

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Anaconda Navigator -> at the environment, go to the base(root)-> open terminal
2. type this command:
   conda install -c conda-forge spacy

[Spacy configuration in Anaconda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTKeb.png)

[Spacy configuration in Anaconda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Oym0.png)

[Spacy configuration at Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRtDP.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To install spacy in jupyter notebook.

1. Open cmd or anaconda prompt.
2. run `pip install spacy` as the base user.
3. it will now work in jupyter notebook but it may take some time to import the modules.