# OSMnx wont open in Juypter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda, osmnx

I downloaded osmnx via conda using the code:

```
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority osmnx
```

This comes from the osmnx documentation: https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

I can see the module has downloaded because in the Anaconda Prompt I can type `conda activate ox`and it works.  However when I go into my jupyter notebook and type

```
import osmnx as ox
```

I get the following error:

​

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-7e05e48535cd> in <module>
----> 1 import osmnx as ox
      2 
      3 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osmnx'
```

Please advise as to what I can do. Thanks

Comment: Make sure you have Jupyter configured to use Conda envs, e.g., see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43197286/570918 That is, make sure to install `ipykernel` in the **ox** env and `nb_conda_kernels` in whatever env has your Jupyter installed (you only need one; for most it is **base**). Launch Jupyter from the latter env activated (likely it's **base**, not **ox**), then select the **ox** env as the kernel for a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Sorry for the basic question, but I assume I need to type “conda install nb_conda_kernels” and “conda install ipykernel” in the Anaconda prompt. Is that right? It seems like the env directory must be typed here “conda install [env directory] ipykernel” and I’m not sure how to find the name of the directory. Can you advise?

Comment: No problem. `conda install -n base nb_conda_kernels` and `conda install -n ox ipykernel`. Then `conda activate base` and `jupyter notebook`. You should then see the option to use **ox** as a kernel in your Jupyter notebooks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your terminal, run:

```sh
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority osmnx jupyterlab
conda activate ox
python -m ipykernel install --user --name ox --display-name "Python (ox)"
jupyter lab
```

This installs OSMnx and JupyterLab into a conda environment called `ox`, activates the environment, installs an ipython [kernel](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments) in the environment, then launches JupyterLab.

See also

- [Conda environments not showing up in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook)
- [Conda environments not showing up in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook)
- [How to use Jupyter notebooks in a conda environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58068818/how-to-use-jupyter-notebooks-in-a-conda-environment)
- [How to add conda environment to jupyter lab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004311/how-to-add-conda-environment-to-jupyter-lab)
- [Link Conda environment with Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37433363/link-conda-environment-with-jupyter-notebook)
- [In which conda environment is Jupyter executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085665/in-which-conda-environment-is-jupyter-executing)