# Jupyter-notebook failed to import python packages

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to use `numpy` in Jupyter Notebook in a Python3 virtual environment, but the encountered an error.

In terminal, I did:

```
$ python3 -m venv py3env
$ source py3env/bin/activate
(py3env)$ jupyter notebook
```

And on the Jupyter page, I created a new notebook and executed the followings

```
!pip install numpy
import numpy as np
```

And the resulting output is this:

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Users/MyName/py3env/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.20.2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d83b6b4f94f9> in <module>
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install numpy')
----> 2 import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

The package is already installed but still cannot be found...?

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: You need to configure notebooks with multiple environments. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37433363/link-conda-environment-with-jupyter-notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be using pip from a different python installation.

To install with the same python executable as your jupyter kernel, in one cell run:

```py
import sys
```

Then in another cell run:

```
!{sys.executable} -m pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you are trying to call a dependency you installed on a virtual environment, attempt to reinstall numpy on jupyter, then try again.