# Adding Python 2 notebook to Jupyter

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I have anaconda installed and have the ability to create a new Jupyter file using Python 3 notebook. I would like to add Python 2 as another notebook/kernel.

I have downloaded/installed Python 2.7, but am unable to get it to show up in Jupyter. I have tried multiple methods found on stack overflow.

I used [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30492913/6490846) to install Phython 2.7, but it is still not showing as a notebook option in Jupyter.

Can someone please walk me through how to install a new notebook in Jupyter. Thank you

Comment: what is the output of `ls $(jupyter --data-dir)/kernels`?

Comment: Invalid switch - "kernels".

Comment: oh is this windows?

Comment: Yes, I should have clarified