# Running Jupyter with Python 2

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have two versions of Python (2 and 3) installed. How can I run Jupyter notebook only with the Python 2 interpreter?

Comment: I knew that solution, but in my case I dont' work with conda. I have installed versions python without conda.

Comment: That answer linked to the non-anaconda version. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34464003/2308683