# Jupyter notebook only runs in python [root]

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

My question actually has two parts. So I just started to learn python language and downloaded Anaconda.
My friend recommended me to use Jupyter since it's relatively easy to use for beginners.
1) He told me to firstly type
**'conda upgrade jupyter'** in the Anaconda prompt (Btw I'm using Python 2.7)

and then I shall be able to run Jupyter by typing in:
**'jupyter'**

However, the prompt only gives me:

```
**(C:\Users\Kester\Anaconda2) C:\Users\Kester>jupyter
usage: jupyter-script.py [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir]
                     [--runtime-dir] [--paths] [--json]
                     [subcommand]
jupyter-script.py: error: one of the arguments --version subcommand --config-dir --data-dir --runtime-dir --paths is required**
```

So I use the second method to run the Jupyter
I typed 'jupyter notebook' to open Jupyter.

2) But this time I got another problem, which is that only **Python[root]** is available when creating a new notebook. On the other hand, the terminal is not accessible, too.
[Unaccessible Terminal and Python [root] only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0r7C.png)
I tried the method of removing nbsignature file under the jupyter folder. But it simply doesn't work.
Any Help please?

Comment: Anyone please explain why this is happening? I was using Windows 8.1 yesterday and everything works perfectly. I updated it to Windows 10 and Jupyter just starts to malfunction. I tried to reinstall the Anaconda for several times. But this problem just repeats.

Comment: `But this time I got another problem, which is that only Python[root] is available when creating a new notebook` - what did you expect here? - `On the other hand, the terminal is not accessible, too` - terminals only work on unix environments.

Comment: I'm expecting to use Python 2 when creating the notebook.

Comment: I was able to initiate my Jupyter by simply typing 'jupyter' and I could create a new notebook in Python 2. But now I can't neither simpy typing  'jupyter' to initiate it nor can I create a Python 2 notebook. I don't get it, is there any problem with the paths when Jupyter is installed?

Comment: The point is, if you go to Jupyter's try page (on the website), you can create a notebook with R, Python 2, Python 3, Ruby, Haskell, Bash, etc. So why I'm only being able to use Python[root] when I installed it on my anaconda?

Comment: All those kernels are not shipped by default. If you want any of those, you have to install them by your own. Here you can learn how to install python kernels. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook

Comment: I'm having the same problem (python[root]), though I'm using python 3. Potentially, I will do a clean reinstall of windows 10 soon. @cel, I'm also using just one kernel but it seems not to workl properly

Answer (score 20):

You just need enter in Terminal:

```
jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 3):

i was also having the same problem on windows but simply giving 'notebook' instead of 'jupyter notebook' worked for me.

instead of 'python -m jupyter notebook'
'python -m notebook' creates the notebook

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to use project [jupyterlab](https://jupyter.org/)

Installation:

`python -m pip install jupyterlab`

Usage:

`python -m jupyterlab`

Answer (score 0):

The resolution appears to be uninstalling `nb_conda_kernels`. See: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1630

The command I executed was for both Anaconda2 & Anaconda2 running on my machine was: `conda uninstall nb_conda_kernels`