# Use pyevolve in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, genetic-algorithm, pyevolve

Pyevolve is usually used in python 2.7. Is there any way we can install and use pyevolve in python 3 ? I know there is another package DEAP for genetic algorithms compatible with python 3 but somehow I have to use pyevolve.

I have tries but I think it is not supported so pip install pyevolve is throwing error.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this PR:  https://github.com/perone/Pyevolve/pull/79

The repo is here:  https://github.com/BubaVV/Pyevolve

`sudo pip3 install future`

then inside of the module folder (after you clone/download it), run:
`sudo python3 setup.py install`

Answer (score 1):

It is a little simpler now (Aug 2021) ...

```
sudo pip3 install future
git clone https://github.com/BubaVV/Pyevolve.git
cd Pyevolve; sudo python3 setup.py install
```

This is enough. I tested it with python3 code on both Windows Linux and MacOSX (Intel).

Answer (score 0):

pyevolve currently does not support python 3.x

If you want to use pyevolve you need to use python 2.x or rewrite it yourself. Seems like there was already an attempt to port it to [python3](https://github.com/perone/Pyevolve/issues/68), but this repo wasn't updated in over a year.

Comment: hi did you manage to find  a solution for version 3 or 3.5 at least because i am still stuck ,i want to use python 3

Comment: Please see the answer by Lotus. He added python 3 compatibility, although his fork isn't merged yet (as of September '17)

Answer (score 0):

Install both the kernel python 2 and 3 if you still want to try pyevolve.
Follow the installation guide at 
[Using both Python 2.x and Python 3.x in IPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook)