# Anaconda using Using both Python 2.x and Python 3.x in IPython Notebook

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

using the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook) Using nb_conda_kernels I almost have it going,, but I seem to have only the very basic Python Interpreter in my environments. What I want is a full Anaconda environment for each version of Python, with all the libraries? How can I do that?

Comment: Have you installed additional packages in your envs? The conda envs do not inherit any package from the toplevel environment

Comment: No, exactly, I am hoping there is some way to have full Anaconda installs in each env?

Comment: to avoid having to add each package one by one manually

Comment: you should clone your base environment if that is what you want... otherwise you can play around with `requirements.txt`

Comment: So How can I clone the base env? and as well that does not provide for installing same packages in the new P2 env? Since the base is p3 sorry not to be more clear in orig question

Comment: otherwise, if all you want is the full anaconda env, just issue `conda install anaconda` after activating your env.. and do not forget to have a look at the anaconda cheatsheet for more quick hints

Comment: I'll give that a go.

Comment: try `conda install anaconda python=2`

Comment: in the env or out?

Comment: sorry I mixed up the syntax.. the `python=2` should be upon creating the env

Comment: if in a Jupyter NB with Python (conda-env:py2.7) active and I run conda install anaconda python=2 I get following specifications in conflict: anaconda tensorflow -. Proto buff ==3.0.0b2 tenor flow ->python 3.5* Use condtion info.. To see dependencies for each pkg? So this does not allow me to add anaconda to the env in Jupyter.

Comment: There seems to be a conflict in creating a Condtion NB kernel/env and getting Anaconda associated/installed with the correct NB kernel/env?

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is to create a environment with some predefined set of packages. From the command line, and possibly outside any conda environment, try something like (`py2` can indeed any name you want):

```
conda create --name py2 python=2 anaconda
```

See http://conda.pydata.org/docs/help/help.html for more details, or for a quick look: http://conda.pydata.org/docs/_downloads/conda-cheatsheet.pdf