# Is there a way to use python 2.x and 3.x in same virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, jupyter

I want to use jupyter with both the versioned kernel of python in a virtualenv. How can I do that?

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34464003/2272172

Comment: You'd need two virtualenvs. Jupyter runs the separate kernels.

Answer (score -2):

you can use `tox` to setup multiple virtualenvs instead ... that would generally be the standard solution