# PYTHON: Installed Python 3 Kernel in Jupyter Now I can't call even Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, anaconda, environments

So I wanted to have the option of running python 3 or python 2 through my jupyter notebook. 
So I followed Stack Overflow advice detailed here:
[Using both Python 2.x and Python 3.x in IPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook)

Didn't work:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7 ipykernel
conda create -n py35 python=3.5 ipykernel
```

This did:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7
source activate py27
conda install notebook ipykernel
ipython kernel install --user`

`conda create -n py35 python=3.5
source activate py35
conda install notebook ipykernel
ipython kernel install --user
```

but now when I ran `import numpy as np` I get :

`No module named numpy`

I checked and I have 3 environments py35, py27 and root and I'm on root. And when I go to the terminal and pip install numpy, it tells me that it's already installed!

Is there anyway that I can use both kernels and have all my packages show. Or at least undo all this. Thanks!

Comment: You don't seem to have installed numpy in either of your two new environments

Comment: conda environments are completely isolated from each other. You have to install your packages into each of them separately. To do so, use `conda install -n py27 numpy` and `conda install -n py35 numpy`. If you want to use  the full stack of scientific packages, consider using `conda install -n py27 anaconda`