# I update to pandas 0.18 with conda update command. But my jupyter notebook cannot import that version and keep on using 0.15

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have the latest version of pandas (0.18). But when I import it from jupyter, the version shows 0.15 instead. What happened and how can I resolve this?

Comment: make sure that jupyter and pandas are in the same conda environment, or use kernels: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook/30492913#30492913

Comment: No, it doesn't work. And I check the juypter is in py27_2 while pandas 0.18 is in py27_0.  But juypter_core is in py27_0.  I am confused