# How to run ipython notebook with python 3(No Anaconda)

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm writing some codes on ipython notebook.

I have both versions of python installed(in my virtualenv), and I normally open ipython notebook with the command below.

```
ipython notebook my_notebook.ipynb
```

However, the command above opens the notebook with python 2.7 whereas I need to open it with python 3.

I tried to install ipython3 to use,

```
ipython3 notebook my_notebook.ipynb
```

but it cannot be installed on my machine at the moment. And I'd not want to install Anaconda on my machine as well.

Can anyone please suggests me the way that I can open the notebook with python 3?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: my answer here may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34464003/2272172

Comment: You write "... but it cannot be installed on my machine at the moment". Why? Is there an error message? Or is it due to external constraints?

Comment: @nostradamus when I typed command 'install ipython3', it throws a message 'usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]..(continues)'. Whereas ipython(for version 2.7) is installed perfectly well and two versions of python kernel(for jupyter notebook) are installed already so I thought ipython3 does not need to be installed.

Comment: If you have kernels installed for both versions of Python already, you can switch between them in the 'kernel' menu in the notebook. If you still need to install the kernel, see: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html