# Installing self-made package in conda environment does not make it importable

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, python-3.5, conda

I want to install a package I made into one of my conda envorinments (For Python 3.5). Yet, when I use conda list, I can find it (called spbusiness):

```
...
sockjs-tornado            1.0.3                    py35_0  
spbusiness                0.1                       <pip>
sphinx                    1.4.6                    py35_0  
spyder                    3.0.0                    py35_0 
...
```

Now when I want to use it with iPython it raises:

```
ImportError: No module named 'spbusiness'
```

When I import pip and asking for all installed packages:

```
 import pip
 pip.get_installed_distributions()
```

It is found in the \anaconda3\lib\site-packages folder:

```
...    
SQLAlchemy 1.0.13 (c:\users\martin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages),
spyder 3.0.0 (c:\users\martin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages),
spbusiness 0.1 (c:\users\martin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages),
sockjs-tornado 1.0.3 (c:\users\martin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages),
snowballstemmer 1.2.1 (c:\users\martin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages),
...
```

I used the Python interpreter from Anaconda directory ~\Anaconda3\python.exe for setup.py install. It returned:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing [...]\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spbusiness-0.1-py3.5.egg-info
Writing [...]\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spbusiness-0.1-py3.5.egg-info
```

Still I can't use it in iPython nor in Jupyter Notebooks. I probably made something wrong but I can't get it the right way.

Thanks for help in forward.

Martin

Comment: You probably started ipython from a different environment and didn't install an ipython kernel in your conda environment. My answer here may help understanding the relationship between jupyter, kernels and conda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook/30492913#30492913

Comment: I started it from the same env. I activated root. Afterwards I use conda list - the package ist listed. When i start ipython from there, I can't use it. I also never added a new environment so far.

Comment: is ipython installed into root? If you don't start ipython from the same environment, it will not see the packages.

Comment: I open the command line than I do: `activate root` than `ipython`. That should start ipython in the correct directory I guess. In Jupyter I am using the Kernel Python[conda root], which I thought would be the same.