# Installing python 3 package on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

[image]

I try to install seaborn using `!pip install seaborn` and `!conda install seaborn` but both install the python 2.7 version and I need the python 3.5 version. I use `!pip3 install seaborn`, it says that:

```
'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

What should I do to install that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using both Python 2.x and Python 3.x in IPython Notebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook)

Comment: @hansaplast where is the duplicate?

Comment: @william007, it's not an identical duplicate, but it will point you to the right way of thinking about the problem. Calling `!pip` or `!conda` from a notebook is not the right way of solving this - it will not install into the environment/interpreter of the current kernel. See my explanation about kernels - this is probably the best way to go for you.

Comment: @cel I didn't see instruction on how to install package in your post actually..

Comment: it's simple: after having installed the kernel as described in the post, activate the environment in your command line, install the packages with conda or pip. If you run the kernel in notebook now, you can import the package.

Comment: @cel I am using windows, and do you mean activate environment in command prompt? If yes, how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will work

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

and after that you can use pip3 to install seaborn

Answer (score 0):

`!pip3 install --user seaborn`

This will work.