# How to switch python env in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter

My development environment is Anaconda3 with a virtual environment "OpenCV3".
I can run Jupyter in my main enviroment, but I don't know how to run jupyter in virtual environment "OpenCV3".

could you please show me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following options are available (there may be others available)

- change `conda` environment from the terminal (using the appropriate command corresponding to your OS) and run `jupyter notebook`.
- Install an ipython kernel for each environment as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30492913/6212875). This will enable you to switch between environments directly in Jupyter, without having to manually switch among environments, from the `Kernel>Change Kernel` menu.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But I have check my Anaconda does not included **nb_conda_kernels** package. And I can't install, due to don't support Python3.6.

Comment: I tried to Manually registering kernels. I have done install **conda install notebook ipykernel** in both main environment and opencv3 environment. But as I enter jupyter notebook. It still have only main environment listed. I can't activate opencv3 environment.

Comment: @SamYao  Did you perform a `ipython kernel install --user` in each environment when you attempted to manually register kernels, as described in the answer?

Comment: I got it!!! I manually add another kernel.json in "Jupyter kernels" folder. and it works!!!! Thank you.