# Jupyter can't find keras' module

Tags: python, anaconda, keras, jupyter-notebook

I have installed Tensorflow and Keras by Anaconda (on Windows 10), I have created an environment where I am using Python 3.5.2 (the original one in Anaconda was Python 3.6). 
When I try to execute `import keras as ks`, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'`.

I have tried to solve this issue by `sys.path.append(C:\\Users\\ ... \\Anaconda3\\python.exe)`

with both notebook and console, but I continue to get the same error.

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: It usually means that you're either not using the right python or kernel. First thing, check which `jupyter` you use with `which jupyter` (*nix): it should be the jupyter of the virtual env. If it is, check that you use the right kernel inside the notebook. If it still does not work, check that you indeed installed `keras` in the virtual env and not your global env.

Answer (score 8):

Please try the following:

Run these in the jupyter notebook cell:

```
import sys

sys.path

sys.executable
```

It may not be pointing to your virtual environment but to the root

**The fix is to** install the jupyter notebook from inside your virtual environment

```
$ . your_env/bin/activate

(your_env)$ python -m pip install jupyter
```

Now you can import tensorflow or keras

Comment: pip install jupyter option worked for me. Thank You!!

Answer (score 4):

Jupyter uses iPython under the hood, for python. So when you install Jupyter, it will also install iPython. There was one issue when I installed keras and Jupyter: I already have iPython installed in my root Anaconda environment. This is the output after I install Jupyter and keras:

```
In [2]: import sys; sys.path
Out[2]: 
['/home/user/anaconda3/bin',
 '/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python36.zip',
 '/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6',
 '/home/user/.ipython']
```

Notice that even though I am inside my conda environment, it still looks for libraries in my root conda environment. And of course keras isn't there.

The step to fix is simply re-activate my environment, with:

`source deactivate && source activate [my_env]`

Then I am using a correct ipython:

```
Out[2]: 
['/home/user/anaconda3/envs/ml3/bin',
 '/home/user/anaconda3/envs/ml3/lib/python36.zip',
 '/home/user/anaconda3/envs/ml3/lib/python3.6',
 '/home/user/.ipython']
```

Comment: I am also not seeing the 'envs' directories when I print the sys.path. Unfortunately, doing a deactivate and activate doesn't change anything. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: As to not seeing the `envs`, you are probably on your `root` conda environment. Trying install kera in your virtual conda environment and activate it, to see if that works for you. If not, you should make a new question with more detail about *your* issue (OS, steps on what you did...), that will help people to understand your issue.

Answer (score 1):

(Not an answer but some troubleshooting hints)

sys.path is not the path to your Python executable, but the path to the libraries.

- Check where Keras is installed and check your sys.path. How exactly did you install Keras?
- Try to execute the same command from the Python interpreter. Do you have the same issue?
- How did you install Jupiter, is the sys.path visible from there the same as sys.path visible from your Python interpreter?
- Do Jupiter and Keras use the same version of Python?

You might try to uninstall Jupiter and install it again, and hope that the new installation picks up the packages which are already installed. What could happen is that you have more than one Python installation and different libraries being installed to the different places. sys.path, when requested from different environments, might give you a hint if that's true.

Comment: 1) I have installed Keras using Ancaonda (*conda install -c conda-forge keras=2.0.2*)   2)Yes   3)Yes   4)Maybe Jupyter uses  Python 3.6 instead 3.5, how could I check this? How could I completely uninstall Jupyter?

Comment: import sys; print (sys.version)

Answer (score 0):

The kernel in console and jupyter are not necessarily the same, and the problem might be that you are not on python 3.5.

```
    python --version
```

should tell you what is running in the console, and in jupyter you should see it as a choice on starting a new notebook. For me, the information in

[Using both Python 2.x and Python 3.x in IPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook)

was very helpful.

Comment: I have tried to follow your suggestion, but I have the same issue. I suppose that my jupyter notebook isn't working with the same Anaconda's Python environment. How could I completely uninstall Jupyter?

Comment: I would reinstall Anaconda altogether.

Comment: @ pgrenholm I have tried to reinstall all, but I haven't got any result.

Comment: Try this doc page: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-python-2-and-3

Answer (score 0):

I have realized that I had two different Jupyter's directories, so I have manually deleted one on them. Finally, I have reinstalled Anaconda. Now Keras works properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a windows/mac user who are working on Jupyter notebook “pip install keras” doesn't help you .Try the below steps.It was solved for me 
1. In command prompt navigate to the “site packages” directory of your anaconda installed.
2. Now use “conda install tensorflow” and after “conda install keras” 
3. Re-start your Jupyter notebook and run the packages.

Answer (score 0):

Acually, I did this command `pip install keras` and `sudo -H pip3 install keras` and `pip3 install keras`. None of them worked. I added the following command and everything worked like a charm:
`pip install Keras`. Yes a capital 'K'

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this problem.

First, the diagnosis. When I run `which python` in a terminal window on my Mac (the same terminal I used to launch `jupyter`, I get `/Users/myusername/.conda/envs/myenvname/bin/python`, but when I run the same command from a terminal *within Jupyter*, I get `/usr/bin/python`. So Jupyter isn't using the correct python executable; the version it's using doesn't have any of my packages installed.

But `which jupyter` returns `/usr/bin/jupyter`; it's using a version of jupyter that isn't coming from within my conda environment. I ran `conda install jupyter` and now `which jupyter` returns `/Users/myusername/.conda/envs/myenvname/bin/jupyter` (for some reason I had to restart the terminal window for this to take effect.) Then if I relaunch `jupyter notebook`, the notebook is using the correct version of Python and I have access to all my installed conda packages.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
I added the Conda environment as a new kernel.

First, install ipykernel:

```
conda install ipykernel
```

Next, create the kernet:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name tf-gpu --display-name "TensorFlow-GPU"
```

Now, when you run your notebook, change the kernel to the new one, to "TensorFlow-GPU" in this example.