# Cannot get keras for anaconda windows

Tags: keras, anaconda

I have tried all the methods available to install keras but of no use. when I install it using anaconda prompt it, it installs along Thano. But eveytime I import in jupyter file, jupyter can not find it and gives this error above:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

Comment: Are you opening jupyter/spider in the conda environment? Have you installed them via conda?

Comment: Yes I am using jupyter and spyder under conda environmnet. I have install couple of other libraries too that works just fine. Only Keras, Theano both are showing above error.

Comment: I had some weird problems with anaconda, I gave it up and used a regular python 3.5. The only thing I can't do (because lack of adm privilege) is to install a proper CUDA kit or lib to work with GPU.

Comment: Use `import sys` , `print(sys.executable)` to make sure you are running same python in your terminal and jupyter/spyder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jupyter can't find keras' module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557881/jupyter-cant-find-keras-module)