# Python Jupyter notebook: Python3 displays, however Python2 runs

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to set up my Ubuntu 16.04 server on GSE(Google Compute Engine). I run into a problem here.

[image]

You can see from the up right corner, it is Python 3 kernel already.

For now, I think my the problem occurs because I first followed the instruction from [Using both Python 2.x and Python 3.x in IPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook):

1. Create this directory: `mkdir -p ~/.ipython/kernels/python3`
2. Create this file `~/.ipython/kernels/python3/kernel.json` with this

   content:
       {
           "display_name": "IPython (Python 3)", 
           "language": "python", 
           "argv": [
               "python3", 
               "-c", "from IPython.kernel.zmq.kernelapp import main; main()", 
               "-f", "{connection_file}"
           ], 
           "codemirror_mode": {
               "version": 2, 
               "name": "ipython"
           }
       }

   And then I installed jupyter(for python3 I think) via pip3:

   $ sudo apt-get install ipython3
   $ pip3 install jupyter

But How am I gonna fix this here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out. The only thing you need to do is to restart the instance. I have no idea why it's. But it somehow fixs my problem here.