# no module named 'pandas' after changing kernel in jupyter notebook (kernel dead)

Tags: python, pandas, module, jupyter, conda

I was trying to be able to select to create a 2.x or 3.x python notebook in Jupyter Notebook. So I followed the solution I found here at Stack: [Using both Python 2.x and Python 3.x in IPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook)

[creating a 2.x or 3.x python notebook in Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX7z5.png)

after that, I can't run a cell at Jupyter without the following error:

[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WW2N0.png)

I've already tried reinstalling conda, the packages, jupyter, and creating a new env. Nothing works.

Any ideas?

one more thing, after reinstalling conda, all my jupyter notebooks shows the **Kernel Dead** error below:

**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin/python'**

Comment: Kernel?  You mean Python version, right?

Comment: yeap. it's a 'Kernel error'. at the jupyter it shows 'kernel dead'

Answer (score 1):

run the command... pip install pandas

if it returns that pip is an unrecognized command, then copy all of this
https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

save it in a file called, get-pip.py
then run in command prompt or terminal: python get-pip.py

After that run pip install pandas

Comment: If you have Python 2 and 3 both installed, make sure to use the pip for 3, not 2.

Comment: hey Michael! thanks!

one more thing, after reinstalling conda, all my jupyter notebooks shows the error below:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin/python'

I believe the kernel is linking directly to this py36 I created when I tried the first step I explained.

(I didn't tried your suggestion yet. just in case the update changes anything)

Comment: I need to know ur OS. Then I can help you find your $PATH

Comment: Linux Ubuntu
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Comment: @MichaelPresman i fixed it with:

python3 -m pip install ipykernel

python3 -m ipykernel install --user

tks again

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with:

python3 -m pip install ipykernel 
python3 -m ipykernel install --user

tks y'all!