# easy way to use both python 2.x and 3.x in ipython notebook anaconda version in Windows 10?

Tags: ipython, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am using Windows 10. I have anaconda2 64bit installed. I have been using python 2.7. In my C drive, I see a folder for Python27 and one for Python34. I see a python executable in the Python27 folder but not in the Python34 folder. if I run

```
where anaconda
```

in DOS I get

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Scripts\anaconda.exe
```

and in that directory, I also see a python.exe file.
I tried the following in Windows Powershell

```
conda create -n ipykernel_py3 python=3 ipykernel
activate ipykernel_py3
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

and then I restarted ipython notebook. I don't see a version of python 3 when I use the pulldown "new" button on the ipython notebook gui (on the right hand side). Can anyone say what is wrong? I was following 
http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html
Thank you.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook/30492913#30492913

Answer (score 0):

configure the python2.7 environment:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7 
source activate py27 
conda install notebook ipykernel 
ipython kernel install --user
```

configure the python3.4 environment:

```
conda create -n py34 python=3.4 
source activate py34 
conda install notebook ipykernel 
ipython kernel install --user
```