# Unable to use pyodbc module in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter, I am trying to pull sql data through a obdc connection,using pyodbc.  I get the below error.  I am able to use pyodbc in spyder using python 2.  I have tried re-loading pyodbc module from the command line without success.  Any ideas?

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-b8f1855c5265> in <module>()
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 import pyodbc

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'
```

Comment: You might have multiple python installs. Are you using python 2 kernel or python 3 kernel in Jupyter? `pyodbc` may be installed on former and not latter.

Comment: Jupyter is a 3, my previous work in spyder is 2.  I've seen the suggestion that there may be multiple python installs on the internet.  How do I rectify this problem.  I have not been able to find directions.  Thank you btw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially, your machine has two version installations of Python. Hence, the module `pyodbc` corresponds to only one version, 2, and not the other, 3. You can do one of the following:

1. Add both the Python 2 kernel to your current Jupyter installation. Then, run your needed notebook under Python 2 to have access to all its modules like pyodbc and spyder. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37857536/1422451):

   ```
   python2 -m pip install ipykernel

   python2 -m ipykernel install --user
   ```
2. Install pyodbc for Python 3 such as below command line:

   ```
   python3 -m pip install pyodbc
   ```

Comment: Thank you for this guidance.  For anyone that comes to this post:  When I downloaded and installed Anaconda, it placed Anaconda2 and Anaconda3 in my programs list.  I opened the Anaconda Command Prompt in Anaconda3 and installed pyodbc as suggested above (w/o  'python3').  It installed pyodbc, and my Jupyter notebook works!

Comment: Great to hear! Glad it all worked out. Now try installing the R kernel for Jupyter is another challenge -of course if you use R =)