# Problem with Python Version And Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

So I created a python 2.7 env "gdsenv" using anaconda:

[image]

Then I installed the jupyter kernel:

[image]

...so far it seems good.

The problem is that if I open jupyter-notebook, I don't get python 2.7 option (I have python 3.5 installed on another env):

[image]

**Why is that and how can I fix that ?**

Answer (score 1):

See if you can [install an ipython kernel for python2](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-kernel.html).

I don't have anaconda installed, but here's how it works for a virtual environment created with `python2 -m virtualenv jupyter-test`:

1. Install jupyter:
   `python2 -m pip install jupyter`
2. Install ipython kernel for python2:
   `python2 -m pip install ipykernel`
   `python2 -m ipykernel install --user`
3. Start jupyter not[![ebook
   `jupyter notebook`][1]][1]

You should now be able to create a python2 kernel:

[image: Python 2 Notebook]

See also this question which seems related: 
[Using both Python 2.x and Python 3.x in IPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook) .

Comment: Thanks a lot for this helpful answer ! I will try it out. :)