# Run screen jupyter notebook in a conda environment

Tags: linux, ssh, server, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run jupyter notebook from a server through a ssh tunnel in a screen window with

`screen jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8888`

It works, but I am not able to let it run in a conda environment I have created.

I tried creating a screen where I activate the environment and then call the notebook:

```
source activate env37  -->(meaning python 3.7)


(env37) user@server:~$ jupyter notebook --no-browser --port 8889
[I 07:24:11.610 NotebookApp] [nb_conda_kernels] enabled, 4 kernels found
[I 07:24:12.242 NotebookApp] [nb_anacondacloud] enabled
[I 07:24:12.297 NotebookApp] ✓ nbpresent HTML export ENABLED
```

But it didn't work, since in the notebook I see this:

```
3.5.4 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Nov 20 2017, 18:44:38)
```

--> Python is 3.5.

Other ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should change the ipython/notebook kernel rather than changing the environment [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30492913/10889986). I hope that solves your problem!