# How do I delete/refresh available kernels for IPython/Jupyter notebook v4.0?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've recently stopped using `macports` so the kernel.json files I had for various IPython kernels are out of date. I have renamed `~/.ipython` and removed `~/.jupyter` but kernels launched are failing to start with `file not found` errors.

More tellingly, when I run `jupyter-kernelspec list` it still lists all the old kernels I had set up. Where is it getting this information from and what do I need to do to refresh/remove its cache?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As of today:

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

gives you a list (names and paths). Then pick the name and uninstall it:

```
jupyter kernelspec uninstall myKernalName
```

Answer (score 40):

After a brute force search, Jupyter stores kernel info for OS X in `/Users/${USER}/Library/Jupyter/kernels`. This list got copied across from my `.ipython/kernels` list hence renaming it made no difference.

Removing `/Users/${USER}/Library/Jupyter/kernels` fixes the issue.

This is the reference I was looking for: http://jupyter-client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/kernels.html#kernelspecs

Comment: Thanks for sharing - I kept editing the kernel files inside `~/.ipython` after getting some errors, but nothing seemed to help, until your post showed me that they are actually loaded from the `~/Library/Jupyter`. Why is that directory under `~/.ipython` even created?

Comment: recommended! this worked for installing the r kernel even when a complete reinstall anaconda, uninstall of brew, r and rstudio did not work.

Answer (score 23):

This is an issue in Linux also if anyone else runs into it. Check the contents of:

`~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/`

Comment: I can confirm that if you delete the content from the specified location and restart your notebook, it works.

Comment: In addition to deleting I had to run following command:
`ENVS=$(conda env list | grep '^\w' | cut -d' ' -f1);for env in $ENVS; do conda activate $env; python -m ipykernel install --user --name $env; echo "$env"; conda deactivate; done`

Answer (score 20):

Running:

`jupyter --paths`

will list all of the possible locations for everything it uses to run: kernels, extensions, pidfiles, etc.

Comment: It does not list kernel path on macos

Answer (score 12):

adding to jbcoe's answer, if you're using macOS, the two locations where you should expect kernels to be installed are

```
/Users/${USER}/Library/Jupyter/kernels
```

and

```
/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels
```

Answer (score 10):

You may run 
`jupyter kernelspec list` in terminal or
`!jupyter kernelspec list` in a notebook cell
to see a list of available kernels and the locations.

Comment: I have both python2 and python3 but , above command doesn't show python3 in jupyter.

Comment: It sounds like you need to install Jupyter for Python 3 see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831854/how-do-i-add-python3-kernel-to-jupyter-ipython

Comment: In my notebook, when I click Change Kernels, I see over five kernels there. But the `jupyter kernelspec list` command lists only one kernel.

Answer (score 8):

To complete the list, in Windows (at least Win 7) it is:

System-level: `C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels`

User-level: `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels`

There is a folder per env(ironment) under the kernels folder.  `kernel.json` within each subfolder is editable to change display name(s), or other parameters.

Comment: 1. navigate to %appdata% 2. Navigate to \jupyter\kernels