# jupyter notebook file not found error after conda reinstall

Tags: ipython, anaconda, jupyter, conda

i did a complete reinstall of anaconda by deleting.

> rm $HOME/anaconda

I started with fresh new python environments but changed the names --> p34 to p36

Now when i start jupyter and want to run an notebook with python 3.6 i get an kernel error message saying it can not find the correct kernel env.

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/plagtag/anaconda/envs/p34/bin/python`

Because it should look it up in

> /home/plagtag/anaconda/envs/p36/bin/python

Where can i update the kernels jupyter uses?

> grep -rn p34 $HOME/.jupyter

gives no result at all :-/

Answer (score 2):

Ok, super easy answer but maybe not the best one.

jupyter stores kernels in in `$HOME/.locals/share/jupyter/kernels`

deleting this directory makes jupyter notebook work normal again.

> rm -rf $HOME/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/*

Comment: This answer here is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976367/how-do-i-delete-refresh-available-kernels-for-ipython-jupyter-notebook-v4-0