# Anaconda Jupyter notebook uses /usr/bin/python3

Tags: python, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04, jupyter

I have installed Anaconda3-4.4.0 on Ubuntu 16.04. I can't find any variation of virtualenv, PATH hacking, or modifications to kernel.json, that stops it from using /usr/bin/python3 when creating a new notebook. I want it to use the anaconda installed version exclusively so I can have different versions of packages in the anaconda environment. I have removed my ~/.jupyter and ~/.ipython. I have tried virtual environments and everything I can think of.

What do I have to do to get it prevent it from using the system installed version of python3.

Comment: Well, what is your PATH? What is "it" that is using that Python?

Comment: Jupyter has several commands to see the configurations. `kernelspec`, for example, or https://stackoverflow.com/a/38706165/2308683 but I don't think Jupyter comes pre-installed with Anaconda kernel

Answer (score 3):

I found a kernel.json from 2015 buried down in .local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json that was pointing to /usr/bin/python3. Moving it out of the way seems to have fixed things.

The strategy was to use jupyter --paths to find the places it looks and check each one.