# How can I run atom and hydrogen within a conda env using bash script?

Tags: python, ipython, atom-editor, conda, hydrogen

I used to have a simple bash script that I was using to activate a conda env and then run atom. Then, I could run python code using hydrogen which could automatically see the packages inside myenv.

The previous bash scrip was sth like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

source activate myenv && 
atom
```

Since conda > 4.4 that 'source activate' does not exist anymore, I had to revise the script to:

```
#!/bin/bash

source /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh &&
conda activate myenv &&
atom
```

However, hydrogen does not detect myenv anymore and runs the code from the base env which results into error due to packages missing from the base env.

When I replace atom with spyder, the above script works fine and spyder kernel does see myenv.

Any idea how I can get this fixed?

**Update 1:**

I did some more debugging. It seems that my ipykernel is not assigned to the kernel installed within the activated environment but assigned to the default ipykernel.

When I try `jupyter kernelspec list` in my activate env, I get:

```
python3    /home/ubuntu/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

But on another system, I get

```
/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/myenv/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

which seems to be the right kernel.

Any idea on how to fix this?

**Update 2:**

It seems that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34345798/10161091) resolves the issue in Update 1. Then, I was able to use the accepted answer to load atom within the desired env and have hydrogen run from the ipykernel in that env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source activate` still works as before, although it is no longer the preferred way to activate an environment.

If you're only running a single command, try

```
conda run -n <envname> <command>
```

possibly with sourcing the profile first.

I haven't tried, but a potential problem is that you're using `&&` after sourcing the profile. I assume that the line continuation characters (`\`) got lost there when you wrote the question. Just write the commands into separate lines, so that the profile is loaded *before* bash processes the next command.

Comment: Thanks, but when I try `source activate myenv`, I get `bash: activate: No such file or directory`. I am going to try the rest.

Comment: I did some more debugging. Please see the update above.

Comment: After some more debugging, it see that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34345798/10161091) fixed my issue. Now the ipykernel is actually linked to the right ipykernel within the env.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used the above command to clean up the bash file.

Comment: The "no such file or directory" is probably because the `.../conda/bin/` script is not in your search path. You can use `source .../conda/bin/activate <envname>` if necessary.