# choose python kernel in jupyter

Tags: python-2.7, debian, jupyter, python-3.5, jupyter-notebook

I have installed on Debian Jessie:

Python2.7

Python3.5

I have also installed Jupyter via `pip2` and `pip3`

However when I launch `jupyter-notebook` I can only use python3 as kernel! How can I switch to pyhton2.7 when using Jupyter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using both Python 2.x and Python 3.x in IPython Notebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook)

Comment: the best solution shows how to solve the issue with anaconda. I want to avoid anaconda.

Comment: I think you can adapt [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30493051/347567), though I can now see this is not a true duplicate since you're on Debian instead of OS X.

Answer (score 7):

I tried this with a fresh Debian 8.5 machine on Digital Ocean.

As root, install `pip` and `jupyter` from apt, and the development packages, too.

```
apt-get install python-pip python-dev python3-pip python3-dev libzmq3
pip3 install jupyter
```

Add the kernel for Python2 using the `ipykernel` module. The Python3 kernel is installed, already.

```
pip install ipykernel
python2 -m ipykernel install
```

When you run `jupyter notebook`, you should have both `Python 2` and `Python 3` listed as available kernels. Notice that the Tornado notebook server is serving HTTP on port 8888, which isn't opened by default on many machines. Here is [a script that will run Jupyter for you, opening and closing port 8888 and running on a public IP.](https://gist.github.com/branning/430f3e31cf9e25e95e0228c211da5693#file-run_jupyter-sh)

[image: Jupyter web interface showing both kernels available for new notebooks]

Comment: hello thanks a lot for the answer. I have tired on my machine I get no error but still dont get both python 2 and 3 (only 3).I will try to investigate further.

Comment: the output of `ipython kernelspec install-self` should confirm that a kernel was installed, and it will say which version. You have to `sudo` the kernelspec command, too.

Comment: In recent versions of ipython, the commands should be `ipython kernel install` and `ipython3 kernel install`

Comment: @AbderrahimKitouni thanks, I updated the instructions based on the current docs.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this right now, but jupyter-notebook is probably looking at your `$PATH` variable to find a python. When you type `python --version`, is it `python2`?

If it isn't, you can choose which python to use by [changing your `$PATH` variable](https://superuser.com/questions/488173/how-can-i-edit-the-path-on-linux) so python2 is before python3.

Comment: i tired : python --version the output is Python 2.7.9

Comment: This answer won't help you then. Maybe some links will: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831854/how-do-i-add-python3-kernel-to-jupyter-ipython and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook

Comment: Also look at trying [Anaconda python](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) to drastically simplify installing packages like this. Conda environments might also be the answer to your kernel problem here.

Comment: Hi, I would like to avoid anaconda. The reason is that I run other scripts other packages (computer vision packages). For the moment I use anaconda on a VM...