# Run Python 2 & 3 in Jupyter on Fedora Linux

Tags: python, linux, fedora, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I did a fresh install of Fedora 23 yesterday.  I installed Jupyter per the instructions at https://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html  which means I did this

```
pip install jupyter
```

It seems to run fun for Python 2.  I tried to add support for the Python 3 kernel as per the instructions here [Using both Python 2.x and Python 3.x in IPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook) which means I followed these instructions http://jupyter.cs.brynmawr.edu/hub/dblank/public/Jupyter%20Help.ipynb#1.4.2-Enable-Python-3-kernel.

I restarted the server, opened a new Python 3 notebook, and watched the kernel die 3 seconds later.

It pretty obvious to me there is very little documentation for running 2 & 3 in Jupyter on Linux without using Anaconda.  Can we please make this a Fedora Linux-centric, no Anaconda thread?

Fedora 23, Python 2.7.10 / 3.4.3

thx

Comment: I added a second [answer for non-anaconda users](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34464003/2272172) to the linked question. It is very similar to my anaconda solution. It just replaces conda environments by normal virtualenvs. I myself prefer virtualenvs over installing directly into the system interpreter, but this is a tradeoff between convenience and cleanness.

Comment: Thanks that is also a great resource.  I do think virtualenvs are a great way to manage this issue.  I myself have gotten away without using virtualenvs for a long time.  But this issue has been the one to convince me I need to start using them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[I answered a similar question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34421527/347567), though for Debian. The following worked on a fresh Fedora 23 machine at Digital Ocean. You'll need to install `python-pip`, `python-pip3`, install `jupyter` on one version of Python, and then install the kernel for the other version of Python. First, make sure you have these dependencies installed:

```
dnf groupinstall 'Development Tools'
dnf install gcc-c++
dnf install rpm-build
dnf install python-devel
dnf install python3-devel
```

Then install `pip` and `pip3`:

```
dnf install python-pip
dnf install python3-pip
```

Then, install `jupyter`. We'll use python3 because it's 2016 already!

```
pip3 install jupyter
```

Install the `ipykernel` package for python2:

```
python2 -m pip install ipykernel
python2 -m ipykernel install
```

Edit: the documentation situation has improved, you can probably [just follow the instructions here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html).

I put these instructions in [a handy script in this gist](https://gist.github.com/branning/430f3e31cf9e25e95e0228c211da5693#file-install_jupyter_2_and_3-sh).

I also put up [a script that will run Jupyter for you on a cloud machine](https://gist.github.com/branning/430f3e31cf9e25e95e0228c211da5693#file-run_jupyter-sh), opening and closing port 8888 and running on a public IP.

Comment: Thank you.  I followed your instructions with only 1 small change for fedora 
python-dev => python-devel,  python3-dev => python3-devel.  IMO I do not think most of the documentation makes it clear that you must run BOTH 'pip install jupyter' and 'pip3 install jupyter'

Comment: I managed to get it working on a fresh Fedora 23 machine, though with some difficulty related to installing system dependencies. I'll update this answer with those steps, if you think it would be helpful.

Comment: Wow that's a great resource.  Thanks for documenting that.  I am not sure why it has been so difficult to get this complete information although I suspect it has to do with so many people saying "just use Anaconda".  If someone is on Win/Mac I probably agree but there is absolutely no need for Anaconda on Linux (I really hope that statement does not start a flamewar : / )

Comment: why not use `dnf install python-pip` ?

Comment: For posterity, `dnf install python3-pip` was the command that worked for me. Specifically, I had to `reinstall` using `dnf` to get the `/usr/bin/` folders to show up for `pip3`.

Comment: @roflmyeggo thanks, I updated the instructions, and gave you a bonus script to run jupyter on a cloud machine. It worked for me on a Fedora 23 Digital Ocean droplet. hth