# No output cells generated in Python 3 Kernel of IPython Notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I've tried to install both `python2` and `python3` kernels as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831854/how-do-i-add-python3-kernel-to-jupyter-ipython) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook) (through `pip` and `pip3` `ipykernel install`), but in all the variants I end up with working `python2` kernel and almost-working `python3` one.

python3 kernel is displayed as the option in "New" dropdown menu, but all notebooks created under it don't produce any output.

That is, I can create new cell, paste `print(5)` in there and run it (the runcount to the left will be incremented), but no output cell is produced.

Same (no) reaction is observed on syntactically-wrong code.

Any ideas on where to go?

Comment: Are there any errors in the terminal where you launched the notebook or in the browser's Javascript console when this happens?

Comment: Thanks for care, @ThomasK. Nope, the only warning that arises is 404 GET /static/components/backbone/backbone-min.map, but according to https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/6725 it's pretty much useless anyway (and happens on page load, not on cell execution). js browser console is also clean =\

Comment: @ThomasK update: when I try running e.g. `print 2` it pipes the SyntaxError into terminal where notebook is running. Nothing there on `print(2)` though

Comment: Can you find what type of object is `sys.stdout`? To get output in a pinch, try `print(x, file=sys.__stderr__)` - this should send output to the terminal where you ran the notebook.

Comment: `print(type(sys.stdout), file=sys.__stderr__)` prints `<class 'ipykernel.iostream.OutStream'>` in terminal

Comment: That's what it's supposed to be. I'm not sure what else could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, nevermind, looks like some deeeeep interdependence-out-of-date bug on this specific machine. After one more from-scratch setup it works. Thank you, Thomas, for assistance!