# How do I add python3 kernel to jupyter (Ipython) II

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I've created the environment and Python 3.5.1 opens in bash, but isn't available to Notebook.  I'm trying to follow [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28874046) to adding the Python3 kernel to Jupyter:

```
jupyter kernelspec install-self --user
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-kernelspec", line 7, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.kernelspecapp import KernelSpecApp
ImportError: No module named jupyter_client.kernelspecapp
```

The link to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28874046/1156245) is dead.  Anyone know what the process was?

Comment: this may be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook/

Comment: @cel are you referring to a specific bit of that page?

Comment: well the gist: first install `ipykernel`, then do `ipython kernel install --user`

Comment: @cel Do you know ipython has been succeeded by Jupyter..?

Comment: Nono, that is a misunderstanding. IPython has not been replaced. The interactive shell, the python kernel and the jupyter ecosystem have been separated into individual projects, so that jupyter itself now is language agnostic, as it should be. IPython itself is not obsolete and is used to install the python kernel.

Comment: Hmm well I tried that line with the py3 profile activated and it returned `Installed kernelspec python2 in /Users/myusername/Library/Jupyter/kernels/python2`.

Comment: You can check with `which ipython` if it points to the correct ipython instance (the one in your virtualenv, if you are using one) - if not, you have to install ipython as well.